# Getting ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified error while connecting

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am using oracle 10g. My os is 64 bit. when i connect my c# console application with oracle, it connects successfully. But when i try to conncet oracle with my asp.net project it shows could not resolve the connect identifier specified error.

Comment: Are the connection strings for each project the same?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string for your asp.net project probably needs to be modified. Check the data source, user id, and password and make sure they are correct on the asp.net system.

Comment: connectionString="Data Source= XE;User ID=abcd;Password=123456;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" is this ok?